# Is there available free python server with MQTT and Mosquitto support

Tags: python, mqtt, mosquitto

For my IoT based project, I need a free or very low-cost python server like pythonanywhere with supports MQTT protocol and additionally Mosquitto.

I tried to use pythonanywhere. I just loved it. But it is not supports MQTT protocol. That's why I am looking for a new python server. Is there available it?

Comment: Recommendations are explicitly off-topic here per the [help].

Comment: Also the concept of a MQTT server is meaningless. There are MQTT brokers (e.g. mosquitto, HiveMQ or mosca) and MQTT clients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are MQTT brokers may you could use `test.mosquitto.org`

or you could install it on your PC from [mosquitto](https://mosquitto.org/download/)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The request is for an integrated development/runtime environment, not just a broker. And as the question is off topic (a direct request for a software recommendation should not have been answered)